# how to disable linked click and enable other links?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i want to disable link when i clicked on a link,here is my code:

```
 <a class="cmd-7" href="?cmd=7" style="color:#00F; margin-left:15px; text-decoration:underline">Past 7 Days</a>
<a class="cmd-14" href="?cmd=14" style="color:#00F; margin-left:15px; text-decoration:underline">Past 14 Days</a>
<a class="cmd-30" href="?cmd=30" style="color:#00F; margin-left:15px; text-decoration:underline">Past 30 Days</a>
<a class="cmd-custom" href="?cmd=custom" style="color:#00F; margin-left:15px; text-decoration:underline">Set A Custom Date Range</a>
```

and here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
// Get the cmd query parameter
var cmd = getParameterByName('cmd');
if(cmd) {
// Disable the link
$('a.cmd-' + cmd).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
})
// Add a class to allow styling
.addClass('disabled');
}
});
</script>
```

it gives error

ReferenceError: getParameterByName is not defined

how to remove this error?

i want when i click past 7 days link this link is disabled or ther links enabled,as soon then if i clicked on past 14 days link,past 7 day link is enabled and past 14 days link is disabled.how i do this?

Comment: there's no function with this (`getParameterByName`) name

Comment: see my code in which this function exist

Comment: Are you trying to use `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName`, or `getElementById`?

Comment: where have you declared the function getParameterByName

Comment: there is no element with name cmd, you have not specified any tag with name cmd.

Comment: Instead of using anchor elements why not use radio buttons that way only one can be selected at a time and there is no need to try and toggle anything.

Comment: yes i used getElementsByTagName, getElementsByClassName, or getElementById but same error exist

Comment: i just want when i click past 7 days link this link is disabled or ther links enabled,as soon then if i clicked on past 14 days link,past 7 day link is enabled and past 14 days link is disabled.how i do this?

Comment: if you are using those, make sure you put document infront of it: `document.getElementById('id_here')` and using a class name or tag name will return an array.

Comment: when i used document.getElementByClassName it gives error Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a.cmd-[object HTMLCollection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//var prevClicked;
jQuery(function($){
// Disable the link
$( "a[class*='cmd']" ).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

    if(typeof prevClicked!='undefined'){ $("a[class*='cmd-"+prevClicked+"']").attr('href','?cmd='+prevClicked);} 

    url = $(this).attr('href');
    prevClicked = url.split('=')[1];
    $(this).attr('href',"javascript:;");
  $(this).addClass('disabled'); //adding 'disabled' to the clicked <a> tag
  $("a[class*='cmd']").not(this).removeClass('disabled'); //removing 'disabled' from all <a> tags except the one clicked
});
// Add a class to allow styling

});
</script>
```

Comment: but you see when i clicked its not move the url just disabled

Comment: Lol, I thought you just wanted to add the class `disabled` . How should the URL be moved? You mean you want to hide it?

Comment: @Arif wew! that took me quite a while, check the updated post.

Answer (score -1):

You can add common class to all links so that you can enable all links first and then disable current link with "this" as a reference

Like this in your ready function

Suppose your common class is "cmd-common"

```
$(document).on('click', '.cmd-common', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.cmd-common').attr('disabled',false);
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: when i used your code it gives me error TypeError: $(...) is null
 

$('.cmd-common').attr('disabled',false);

Comment: Have you added that common class on all links?